# Why did syncing with iTunes delete one of my photos folders?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization

I have an iPod Touch, and I tried to sync with apparently more room than my iPod Touch had on it.  So instead of not syncing some new podcasts, it decided to delete one of my photos folders off of my iPod Touch (over 5000 pictures).

Why did the iPod Touch determine that this should be deleted? Why didn't it give me a warning or a prompt so I could have chosen what action to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion 1 :**
I think you would be a new user to the iPod/iPhone/OS X/iTunes family. 
If your afraid or don't understand what is happening during synchronization using iTunes, I suggest you to use a utility called [iPhoneExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/).

Just Explorer the iPhone/iPod/iPad like a file system. 
You would get your images under `Root/User/Media/DCIM/` directory. images are grouped in directories like `100APPLE`, `101APPLE` and so on. Just explore and copy it.

**Suggestion 2:**
Synchronization - means **A single machine and an iPod synchronization**. *Not **multiple** machines and an iPod*. If you synchronizes from **other machine** it will **erase all of your old data**. According to me, you had the problem just because you might have synchronized from other machines iTunes.

Comment: kothari - only a single machine

Answer (score 1):

In my experience iTunes treats photos as the least important content on an iOS device, whenever there is too much music selected to sync a pop up tells me that there was not enough space to sync all of my photos to the iOS device. I don't think this can be changed.

Comment: but why does it delete the whole album.  why not just delete enough pics to free up space.

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I guess that's just how Apple set it up.